# Validation on button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm doing validation first on an email(mandatory and correct format) and then on a file upload(either blank or correct format) on the button submit.
Here the email is validating well but in file upload if it is blank it also shows an error which is not needed.

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

     $("#button").click(function () {

         var email = $("#person_email").val();
         var img = $("#person_avatar").val();

         if (email == null || email == "" || !email.match(/^[a-z0-9_\+-]+(\.[a-z0-9_\+-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*\.([a-z]{2,4})$/))

         {
             $("#valid").show();
             return false;

         } else if (!img == "" || !img.match(/(\.bmp|\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.gif)$/))

         {
             $("#valid_1").show();
             return false;
         } else {
             return true;
         }
     });
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to change

```
(!img == "" || !img.match(/(\.bmp|\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.gif)$/))
```

to

```
(!img == "" && !img.match(/(\.bmp|\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.gif)$/))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use and instead of or. Possibly also worth checking for `null` on this one as well:

```
...
} else if (img != null && img != "" && !img.match(/(\.bmp|\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.gif)$/)) {
     $("#valid_1").show();
     return false;
}
```

The problem is that you're saying "when it's not empty *or* it's an incorrect file format, show the error message". Since `img == ""` will fail the first condition, it falls to the second. Since `""` is not one of your approved file types, it *passes* that test, and goes into the error code.

Instead, you need to say "when it's not empty *and* it's an incorrect file format, show the message". That way, when it's empty it fails the first test, so the entire condition fails.

As it was, it will have been entering the `if` block regardless of what you enter into the field - if it's empty then it's a wrong file type, but if it's not empty then it's not empty so it passes the first test.

Answer (score 1):

```
(!img == "" || !img.match(/(\.bmp|\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.gif)$/))
(!img == "" && !img.match(/(\.bmp|\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.gif)$/))
```

Edit this.